# firebase retrieval returns too early

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following code to retrieve data from firebase db.

```
 firebase.database().ref('/users/' + uid.toString()).once('value').then(snapshot => {
            var data = snapshot.val();
```

Unfortunately, the `then` function gets executed too early before `snapshot.val()` has a value. snapshot has value but not `snapshot.val()`. Anyone run into this? After a second or two, the then() is executed again, and `snapshot.val()` gets a value.

Comment: From the code you shared it is hard to determine what is happening. Can you give us a single snippet that if run shows the problem? `Log.i()` statements are usually very helpful there, especially when you show what they printed, and say what you expected them to print instead.

Comment: data returns null then a second later returns an object. no error

Comment: Never mind. Works now